Self-Studying Real Analysis, am I overthinking?
I'll begin by noting that I've done some real analysis, and I'm wanting to go into more depth with it.
I'm using Carothers' book Real Analysis for self-study. Right from the get-go, I'm having troubles with the exercises—namely, I don't know how much effort should I put into the proofs for the exercises. I also don't know how to check my solutions.
For example, question 1.1

If A is a nonempty subset of $\Bbb R$ that is bounded below, show that A has a greatest lower bound. That is, show that there is a number $m \in \Bbb R$ satisfying: (i) m is a lower bound for A; and (ii) if x is a lower bound for A, then x < m. [Hint: Consider the set -A = {-a : a ∈ A} and show that m = $-\sup(-A)$ works.]

For this, I started with a subset of the real numbers, A, which is not empty and bounded below. Thus, there was at least one lower bound of A, $m \le a$ for all a in A. Next, to prove that there was also a greatest lower bound, I took $-A = \{-a|a\ \in\ A\}$ As $-m \ge -a$ for all a in A, -A is now bounded above, at which point I used the LUB axiom to show that $\sup -A$ exists and is less than or equal to all other upper bounds, took -m = $\sup -A$, and then $m = -\sup -A$ to show that $m\ \ge -x$ where x was an upper bound of -A.
I also feel that there's a simpler possible solution for this problem by taking the set of all lower bounds of A, B, and then applying the LUB property to show there's a value, m, such that $m \ge b$ for all b in B, and that $m \le a$ for all a in A. Thus m is a greatest lower bound for A.
I feel this is wrong, somehow, but I can't figure out where or how it goes wrong. I feel like I'm assuming too much instead of stating things clearly. Am I overthinking this, or have I genuinely made a mistake here? And more generally, how do I critically examine my answers for real analysis questions?

The book you followed might define the above property in the case of least upper bound and asked the reader to verify using that for the analogous greatest lower bound case.
The way you have done is correct.
In the second attempt, it is almost right except for the justification (which you missed) that $m\le a, \forall a \in A.$
Justification follows from the contradiciton argument: Assume that $\exists a'\in A,$ m > a. Then by the definition of $m,$ there exists a $b\in B$ which is greater than the $a'.$ (contradiction) Ergo proved.

To cross-check your answers in RA (or, in fact, any field), ensure that the conclusions derived satisfy the necessary presumptions.   Also, we use " \sup " for supremum under the math environment.
